# Suppress the stack trace in Karma (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, stack-trace, karma-runner

Does anyone know of a way to suppress the stack trace given by Karma when testing AngularJS? (Either via a config option or plugin).

Ideally I want my test report to be nothing more than a list of single line test case failures with the usual summary. I like writing out my test for a given module in one go and then using this as a straight forward *todo* list when writing actual code. This is how I usually have it setup when unit testing other stuff. Instead I get lines and lines of a trace and have to scroll around searching for the only line I care about:

"**browser version (os) my useful test case FAILED**"

I have tried various karma config **logLevel** options, but I still get a trace dump.

**Please note**: I am **not** looking for a debate on the merits of stack traces. I have a specific question and only care about a specific answer. If you know of a plugin that will provide similar or perhaps superior reporting to what I am looking for then **please do** share!

Answer (score 2):

In `karma-test-shim.js` you can set ...

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = 0; // No Stack trace

Error.stackTraceLimit = 2; // Some Stack trace

Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity; // Full stack trace
```

Tested with `kjhtml` (`karm-jasmine-html`) reporter.

Answer (score 1):

Quite some time later, I could only find [this closed issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/100) on karma-jasmine project, suggesting to create a custom reporter locally in config file:

```
var myReporterFactory = function() {

    this.onRunComplete = function(browser, result) {
        var TOTAL_FAILED = 'TOTAL: %d FAILED, %d SUCCESS\n';
        process.stdout.write(
            require('util').format(TOTAL_FAILED, result.error, result.success)
        );
    };

    return this;
};

// ...

plugins: [
  // other karma plugins ...
  {
    'reporter:myReporter': ['factory', myReporterFactory]
}],
```

Not sure how close to your actual result one could get ... quite a long shot. Or better maybe switch to a different reporter. Two examples here:

- [karma-mocha-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter), with its [output](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter#output) and [maxLogLines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha-reporter#maxloglines) options
- [karma-nyan-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-nyan-reporter) (!!), as funny as it can sound, with its *suppressErrorReport* option

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution :

in karma-jasmine-html-reporter `jasmine.css` file
add `display:none` to class `.jasmine-stack-trace`